# Arduino IDE - fails to link compiled subsections in avr-gcc

Tags: arduino, linker-errors, avr, arduino-ide, avr-gcc

Hello StackOverflow Community,

Recently I have been noticing that my Arduino IDE has simply been failing to actually be able to compile and run to any board, from the TTN Uno (which is a smaller Arduino Leonardo), ESP8266 (both in module and WeMos), to the Arduino Uno (R3 SmD version).

I enabled verbose output from the compilers inside of the IDE's preferences. and the lines that it crashes on is when the file .o files get compressed into the final .hex that the avrdude (or esptool) finally pushes into the programmable flash that the boards utilize to operate.

```
Linking everything together...
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc" -w -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p  -o "C:\Users\JTamez\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_806309/sketch_jun27a.ino.elf" "C:\Users\JTamez\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_806309\sketch\sketch_jun27a.ino.cpp.o" "C:\Users\JTamez\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_806309\libraries\DHT-sensor-library\DHT.cpp.o" "C:\Users\JTamez\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_806309\libraries\DHT-sensor-library\DHT_U.cpp.o" "C:\Users\JTamez\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_806309\libraries\TheThingsNetwork\appData.pb.c.o" "C:\Users\JTamez\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_806309\libraries\TheThingsNetwork\deviceData.pb.c.o" "C:\Users\JTamez\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_806309\libraries\TheThingsNetwork\pb_common.c.o" "C:\Users\JTamez\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_806309\libraries\TheThingsNetwork\pb_decode.c.o" "C:\Users\JTamez\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_806309\libraries\TheThingsNetwork\pb_encode.c.o" "C:\Users\JTamez\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_806309\libraries\TheThingsNetwork\CayenneLPP.cpp.o" "C:\Users\JTamez\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_806309\libraries\TheThingsNetwork\TheThingsMessage.cpp.o" "C:\Users\JTamez\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_806309\libraries\TheThingsNetwork\TheThingsNetwork.cpp.o" "C:\Users\JTamez\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_806309\libraries\Timer\Event.cpp.o" "C:\Users\JTamez\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_806309\libraries\Timer\Timer.cpp.o" "C:\Users\JTamez\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_806309/core\core.a" "-LC:\Users\JTamez\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_806309" -lm

wiring.c.o (symbol from plugin): In function `__vector_16':

(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `init'
C:\Users\JTamez\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_806309\sketch\sketch_jun27a.ino.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here


collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am not sure why wiring.c is now causing issues when it has consistently worked for so long. Is this a side effect of corruption, or a external library affecting it? All the Libraries I am using are listed below:

```
Using library DHT-sensor-library at version 1.3.0 in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\DHT-sensor-library 
Using library Adafruit_Sensor at version 1.0.2 in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_Sensor 
Using library TheThingsNetwork at version 2.5.10 in folder: C:\Users\JTamez\Documents\Arduino\libraries\TheThingsNetwork 
Using library EEPROM at version 2.0 in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\EEPROM 
Using library Timer in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Timer (legacy)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize everyone, I figured out that a method I created called 'init()' was interfering with init() inside of wiring.c

Comment: Another great job of the Arduino libraries, spoiling global namespace with common names.